# c/c++ disassembler for emacs and objdump

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to show assembly under the cursor in emacs (spacemacs, on mac os x) and although disaster.el does generate assembly with objdump, it fails to associate lines in source with lines in assembly.  Error: "couldn't find corresponding assembly line".

disaster.el has not been updated in 3 years either, so I'm wondering if there is another package for this, or if we can get disaster.el working?

Comment: I'm not sure why this isn't an issue on its bug tracker...

Comment: no one seems to be maintaining it anyway, but I'll log it when I find the time. https://github.com/jart/disaster

Comment: Did you miss the compiler option `-g`?